# How to trigger register helper method after the dom is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I am creating an application with require, backbone and handlebars.

I have a product tile which will have product title and description. I wrote a helper method in handlebar template(html file) and am registering it on init.

and on page load the helper method is getting executed before the dom load. I want my helper method to execute after the dom load, i tried all the possible scenarios like document.ready, window.onload, document.ready state, setTimeout, none of them helped.

If I placed my method without writing the helpers, then it is working fine, but I need to pass the every class which is under my tile div, because i want to set the height dynamically.

This is what I tried:

Html:

```
<div class="tile">
 <h2 class="headTitle" {{{helper "headTitle"}}}>{{{productTitle}}}</h2>
<p class="headDesc" {{{helper "headDesc"}}}>{{{productDesc}}}</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
define([
'jquery','handlebars','backbone', 'text!template.html'
  ], function(jquery, hbs, backbone, tpl){
  el: "body",
  template : hbs.compile(tpl),
  initialize : function(){
    this.registerCustomHelper();
  },
render: function(){
   $(this.el).html(this.template);
},
registerCustomHelper : function(){
  hbs.registerHelper('helper', function(cname) {
   console.log("should load after dom element is available" + cname);
});
}
});
```

Comment: I think you have things a little backwards. Your template shouldn't be listening for events, something else (probably your view) should listen for the events and then manipulate the HTML appropriately (using say `this.$('.headTitle').css(...)` in the view). Things work smoother when you think of your template as simple text manipulation, keep the logic inside the view.

Comment: @muistooshort : Yes I can do this but the problem is I have 10 elements then it would be tougher.

Comment: @M-S what is tougher about adding a common class to those 10 elements and registering a common event handler in view..?